# InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code happens when emitting IL code with non-void return type

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I am trying to lower down reflection method call time by creating a DynamicMethod, emitting IL code with its IL generator, and then creating a delegate using its CreateDelegate method. So far the call times are reduced significantly even though the new method call still uses (object callObject, object[] params) as parameters.
The problem occurs in the generated IL code when the return type is anything other than void. I have no knowledge of MSIL and did quite a bit of research but found nothing. Here is the code that works:

```
private void Start()
{
    var a = new A();
    var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("Add");

    Type[] paramsTypes = { typeof(object[]) };
    Type[] allTypes = { typeof(object), typeof(object[]) };
    Type returnType = typeof(void);

    var dm = new DynamicMethod("Hi", returnType, allTypes);

    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, paramsTypes);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var del4 = (Action<object, object[]>)dm.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Action<object, object[]>));

    var time = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
    {
        //a.Add(); 132 ms

        //method.Invoke(a, null);// 25 sec

        del4(a, null); // 200 ms
    }

    var ts = DateTime.Now - time;

    Debug.Log($"{ts.Seconds}:{ts.Milliseconds}");
}

public class A
{
    public int a = 0;

    public void Add() => a++;
}
```

The resulting time (only the call time is measured) is so much faster compared to normal MethodInfo.Invoke. However, with the following tweaks, the IL generator throws error:

```
private void Start()
{
    var a = new A();
    var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("Add");

    Type[] paramsTypes = { typeof(object[]) };
    Type[] allTypes = { typeof(object), typeof(object[]) };
    Type returnType = typeof(object);

    var dm = new DynamicMethod("Hi", returnType, allTypes);

    var il = dm.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, paramsTypes);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var del4 = (Func<object, object[], object>)dm.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Func<object, object[], object>));

    var time = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
    {
        //a.Add(); 132 ms

        //method.Invoke(a, null);// 25 sec

        del4(a, null); // 200 ms
    }

    var ts = DateTime.Now - time;

    Debug.Log($"{ts.Seconds}:{ts.Milliseconds}");
}

public class A
{
    public int a = 0;

    public int Add() => a++;
}
```

When the return type expected is something other than void, the following exception is thrown:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) object:Hi (object,object[]): IL_0006: ret
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Edit: Added boxing before return opcode:

```
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, paramsTypes);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Box);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Then the following is thrown:

```
VerificationException: Error in System.Object:(wrapper dynamic-method) object:Hi (object,object[]) Invalid instruction 8c
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work for _any_ return type other than `void`? A return type of `int` should work. For `object`, you would need to emit another `box` instruction. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box?view=net-5.0) for how to do this. That said, I can't even get the version that you claim works, to work on my machine. Maybe it's because I'm using .NET 5...

Comment: @Sweeper I used exactly the int type and it doesn't work. When I switched the dynamic method return type to int and Func return types to int, it worked. But since I want something generic, I need object type to be returned. The problem is probably boxing as you said. But I added boxing before return and it didn't work. And this one works on unity with .Net Standard 4.x , which I believe uses c# 7.3.

Comment: Umm... That's not how you emit a `box` instruction. I've included a link in my first comment to the documentation, telling you which overload of `Emit` you should use, and you don't seem to have read it at all... You should also pass the type that you are boxing, `typeof(int)`, or more generally, `method.ReturnType`.

Comment: Ret requires a value on the stack, the one that is returned, in a non void method. If your method declares returning something but the verifier sees an empty stack on return, you get the exception

Comment: Honestly, IL us hard to get right. If you're new to IL, perhaps consider using "Sigil" (nuget package), which is far clearer when telling you about errors. Alternatively, consider using the Expression API (and in particular the Compile() method)

Comment: 1) `box` should be inserted before returning if value on stack is struct, if value on stack is class, then no `box` required. 2) Personally I recommend write piece of code and compile with regular compiler (e.g. compile C# code in release) and inspect resulting code with decompiler. This will give you perfectly valid MSIL. 3) Don't use `EmitCall` for calling method, use `Emit(OpCode, MethodInfo)` instead